# how do I debug client side browser/HTML-structure performance issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, performance-testing

I have developed my first web application. It is running, and doing what it is supposed to, but some pages have performance issues. I have tuned the application in several areas, but I am completely lost with one issue:

I have a calendar with events, that toggles invisible or visible when a user toggles options. The whole thing is updated client side, with the use of javascript, and JQuery functions. The update is just a little too slow.

I had no experience in debugging this, so I took a guess based on previous reading, that nested tables might be the culprit. I worked for several hours on untangling these as [this article](http://webdesign.about.com/od/speed/a/dont-use-nested-tables.htm) describes. Then it was the issue of making the css work again, and then testing. The performance was unfortunately even worse than before.

**I would like to know if there is a better way to approach my problem, as trial and error will get old in the long run. Can I somehow time the browsers rendering of a `<table>`? How else can I debug performance issues due to client side issues/html structure?** I am hoping for a cross-browser solution, but my main concern is IE8 and Google Chrome. Take a guess on which one is the slow one...

I tried to make a JSFiddle of my specific issue, but it ended up being 20.000 lines of code, and still not working properly. I guess a size performance issue isn't really the best fit for JSFiddles format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you have way too many [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) nodes!

A good tool to start with is [yahoo's yslow](https://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and [google's pagespeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

These tools both look for common performance mistakes and give you tips on how to fix them. They also help with [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) because pagespeed is a pretty big metric when ranking a page.

If my assumption is correct and you have too many DOM nodes the 2 tools will tell you.

Comment: These two first answers are both very interesting! I'm gonna take some time to check out the tools. I'll be returning to accept an answer soon enough :) Thanks

Comment: "There are 1410 DOM elements on the page" Enough for a D-grade judged by yslow

Comment: @KjetilNordin start by trying to minimize that, and maybe you have some event handlers that are too generic and are added to too many DOM elements

Comment: Maybe. I'll start by twisting my brain on how to minimize the number of DOM-elements. I am pretty confident that some of my Javascript functions are slowing down because there are so many elements to iterate through. I'll say you gave me exactly the answer I needed to continue my performance tuning, now a little bit less "wild guessingly". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be related to redraws/repaints of your page or parts of it.

Google Chrome gives you some nice tools to see where redraws happen. You could start by using the "Timeline" in the Developer Tools to see how your site performs.

To see the paints just open your Google Chrome Developer Tools, press "esc" (a little area on the buttom should show up now). Then in "Rendering" check "Show paint rectangles, Show FPS meter" and if you like "Enable continuous page repainting" and "Show potential scroll bottlenecks".
Those might give you an idea on how to improve your performance.

Also check out this video on "Debugging CSS & Render Performance" by Chelsea Derrick https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqc88qWuiI4

Comment: These two first answers are both very interesting! I'm gonna take some time to check out the tools. I'll be returning to accept an answer soon enough :) Thanks